# Mongoose Update Single Value of an object in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i'm currently trying to update an object's value(status) of the id "12345" from "Plan to Watch" to "Watch" in the array(movielist ) of a single user by using the data below

```
    {
       _id: "5d4813c0a14fcd44f83feda8",
       userName : "Dave",
       movielist : 
       [
        {
          _id:"5d29c4922ce984356cea8b48",
              movie:
           {
              _id:"12345"
              title:"The Avengers",
         movieLength:"143min",
           }
          status:"Plan to watch"
        },
        {
           _id:"5d276dd65f27682c26c6041b",
            movie:
           {
              _id:"5d28ca94e2e19d6cbaecdef9"
              title:"The Avengers",
              movieLength:"143min",
           }
      status:"Completed"
         }
        ]
     }
```

I have tried using the mongoose below to change the value:

```
userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(5d4813c0a14fcd44f83feda8,{movielist :{id:12345}},{$set:{movielist :{status:"Completed"}}},callback)
```

But what i got is that the Attribute status that i was trying to update has been removed for object with id "12345" which is the result below :

```
         {
   _id: "5d4813c0a14fcd44f83feda8",
   userName : "Dave",
   movielist : 
   [
    {
      _id:"5d29c4922ce984356cea8b48",
      movie:
      {
         _id:"12345"
         title:"The Avengers",
         movieLength:"143min",
      }
    },
    {
      _id:"5d276dd65f27682c26c6041b",
      movie:
      {
         _id:"5d28ca94e2e19d6cbaecdef9"
         title:"The Avengers",
         movieLength:"143min",
      }
      status:"Completed"
    }
   ]
}
```

I have tried using the mongoose below to change the value:
own below is the schema i have used for this object:

```
userSchema = schema({
                userName: String,
                movielist : [{id :{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'movies', required : true}, status : String}],
            });
```

May i know where kind of horrible mistake did i commit?

Comment: findByIdAndUpdate is the wrong choice here. you need to use findoneandupdate function. Basically you are not trying to find only by id, you want to filter it with parent id and then id under the movie array.

Comment: @Sachin Did you mean this?userModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id:5d4813c0a14fcd44f83feda8},{movielist :{id:12345}},{$set:{movielist :{status:"Completed"}}},callback)

Answer (score 1):

Please update your query to this :

```
userModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: ObjectId('5d4813c0a14fcd44f83feda8'), 'movielist.movie._id': '12345'}, {$set:{'movielist.$.status' :'Completed'}}, {returnNewDocument : true},callback)
```

Comment: The only problem is that i'm going to have multiple users...with potentially the same movies in their list...

Comment: @Dave : when you say same movies ? having same _id : '12345' in multiple objects of movielist array ?

Comment: what i meant is that another user other then user Dave might have the same movie....and I'm referencing from the collection 'movies', the _id :12345 is an id of a document from the collection 'movies', thats why I'm trying to update by using the User's _id than find the movies array for a movie object with referenced id :12345, My apologies if im confusing you...

Comment: Nope i'm still unable to update, it gave me this error "MongoError: Cannot create field 'movie' in element {movielist: [ { _id:
ObjectId('5d29c4922ce984356cea8b48'), id: ObjectId('12345') } ]}"

Comment: @Dave : Can you try now, If you're using mongoose, then it should be able to convert _id passed to ObjectId('') internally. If you've multiple documents with 'movielist.movie._id': '12345', then it will only update one document matching to '{_id: ObjectId('5d4813c0a14fcd44f83feda8'), 'movielist.movie._id': '12345'}' , basically if you're filtering only on _id then go for 'findByIdAndUpdate' also we're using 'findOneAndUpdate' cause you need updated doc back !! If you're using mongoose you can have {new : true} rather than {returnNewDocument : true}..

Comment: i tried this : userModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: ObjectId('5d4813c0a14fcd44f83feda8'), {'movielist.movie._id': '12345'}, {$set:{'movielist.$.status' :'Completed'}},callback)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197514/discussion-between-srinivas-y-and-dave).

Answer (score 1):

can you correct your schema, you wrote stat!

```
         userSchema = schema({
            userName: String,
            movielist : [{id :{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'movies', required : true}, status: String}],
        });
```

Comment: P.s must have made an missed that typo out, anyways i corrected my codd and its still the same result

Comment: also you can do it like let result = await  userModel.findById(5d4813c0a14fcd44f83feda8,{movielist :{id:12345}); and for the next step you say result.status = "Completed"; and finaly result.save();

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of research as well as looking through some other stackoverflow questions, i modified the answers you guys gave me and managed to change that status to "Completed" via the mongoose operator $elemMatch in the filter section of FindOneAndUpdate After the UserId, just want to thanks to all those who have guided me, and really sorry about my typo and being quite bad at this